# Haskell filtering data

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to filter the below data so I can find specific data for example if I wanted to find an item with only apples it would look similar to this output: `[("apple","crate",6),("apple","box",3)]`

```
fruit :: [(String, String, Int)]
fruit = [("apple", "crate", 6), ("pear", "crate", 5), ("mango", "box", 4),
("apple", "box", 3), ("banana", "box", 5), ("pear", "box", 10), ("apricot",
"box", 4), ("peach", "box", 5), ("walnut", "box", 4), ("blueberry", "tray", 10),
 ("blackberry", "tray", 4), ("watermelon", "piece", 8), ("marrow", "piece", 7), 
 ("hazelnut", "sack", 2), ("walnut", "sack", 4)]

first :: (a, b, c) -> a
first (x, _, _) = x

second :: (a, b, c) -> b
second (_, y, _) = y

third :: (a, b, c) -> c
third (_, _, z) = z
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to write interactively one line in Hugs for finding out in what
containers and what quantities apples are available in the store.

Comment: `filter (("apple" ==) . first) fruit`. I would advice to use `ghc` instead, Hugs latest release was in 2006, so the project is "*dead*" for more than a decade.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of alternatives:

```
filter ((=="apple") . first) fruit
[ f | f@("apple",_,_) <- fruit ]
```

The first one exploits your `first` projection, checking whether its result is equal to `"apple"`.

The second one instead exploits list comprehensions, where elements that fail to pattern match are discarded.

Perhaps an even more basic approach is using a lambda abstraction and equality.

```
filter (\(s,_,_) -> s == "apple") fruit
```